# How to remove a lifetime requirement for an application in pyo3

Tags: rust, traits, pyo3, lifetime-scoping

Here's a reduced form of problem: I have a trait

```
pub trait GetIter {
    type IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item=usize>;
    fn get_iter( &self ) -> Self::IntoIter;
}
```

There are several use cases where I can implement `GetIter` on a reference `&'a T`, but not on `T`.  This is fine for pure Rust, but lately I've needed to build a python interface with pyo3.

Since pyo3 wrappers are incompatible with lifetime parameters, I'd like to do something like the following

```
pub struct  NoRef< T > { inner: T }

impl <T> GetIter for NoRef< T > 
    where &T: GetIter
{
    type IntoIter = Vec<usize>;
    fn get_iter( &self )-> Vec<usize> { 
        (&self.inner).get_iter().into_iter().collect() 
    }
}
```

That is, we create a temporary reference internally, just long enough to dump the contents of the iterator to a vector, the drop the reference.  The problem is that Rust doesn't like the constraint `&T: GetIter` -- it wants a lifetime parameter.

Comment: Have you tried declaring it with a `'static` lifetime? The memory management in python is more relaxed, I imagine you would not have problems with `static references. I'm not sure what I'm saying, though.

Comment: Thanks!  Tried two variations: first was

```
impl <'a, T: 'static> GetIter for NoRef< T > 
    where &'a T: GetIter
```
second was
```
impl < T: 'static> GetIter for NoRef< T > 
    where &'static T: GetIter
```
But both gave errors about an variable living too long (I'm no expert but I'd guess it's because rust assumes the reference we create in the function body must have a static lifetime, which means it has to persist after the scope of the function body drops).

Comment: You probably want a HRTB: `where for<'a> &'a T: GetIter`.

Comment: Yes, Adding to @Jmb's answer, I think the `&self.inner` is tryng to constrain it to the lifetime `'a` on the trait and there is no way for the compiler to figure that out. The `&self.inner` is looked at as a "shorter" lifetime/borrow than `'a` and you can't present a short lifetime as a longer one. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=797535f9dfa80b58dc4717c080046853

Comment: That works great!  This problem has a few level of complexity, and since the first level is now nicely resolved, I'm editing the post to include both the solution and the next level of detail.

Comment: Please don't do that. If you have other questions then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), possibly linking to this one for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HRTB:

```
impl < T > GetIter for NoRef< T > 
    where for <'a>  &'a T: GetIter,
{
    type IntoIter = Vec<usize>;
    fn get_iter( & self )-> Vec<usize> { 
        (&self.inner).get_iter().into_iter().collect() 
    }
}
```

Just for added detail, you can check that this compiles/executes correctly with an example:

```
impl <'a> GetIter for &'a Vec<usize> { 
    type IntoIter=Vec<usize>; 
    
    fn get_iter(&self)->Self::IntoIter { 
        (*self).clone() 
    } 
}
```