# Compiler complaining about temporary value getting created but not sure how and where?

Tags: rust, reference, traits, lifetime, borrow-checker

With reference to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75894457/how-to-remove-a-lifetime-requirement-for-an-application-in-pyo3), I tried to compile it with some changes:

```rust
pub trait GetIter<'a> {
    type IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item = usize>;
    fn get_iter(&'a self) -> Self::IntoIter;
}

pub struct NoRef<T> {
    inner: T,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a> GetIter<'a> for NoRef<T>
where
    &'a T: GetIter<'a>,
{
    type IntoIter = Vec<usize>;
    fn get_iter(&'a self) -> Vec<usize> {
        (&self.inner).get_iter();
        vec![]
    }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:16:9
   |
10 | impl<'a, T: 'a> GetIter<'a> for NoRef<T>
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |         (&self.inner).get_iter();
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------ temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |         |
   |         creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
   |         argument requires that borrow lasts for `'a`
```

I am not getting what "temporary value" it is referring to here?

Comment: Not sure where you got confused but the compiler tells you exactly what temporary value it's talking about, `(&self.inner)`, indicated by the `^` below it

Comment: As you've written your mre it's a bit unclear why one would ever implement `GetIter` for `&T` instead of `T` since all methods take `T` by reference anyways, so just `impl GetIter for T` with the bound `T: GetIter` should be enough as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0eb11b24e970d289ad20281a29eb55b8

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are merging all the logically different lifetimes into a single one. But let's go step by step.

In the statement `(&self.inner).get_inner()`, you are creating a [temporary expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes) (`self.inner`), and then take its borrow. As per the documentation, the borrow will only last up to the end of the current statement, that is, to the end of `(&self.inner).get_inner()`. On the other hand, `get_inner` requires a borrow `&'a self`, where `'a` is the same lifetime as basically everything else in your example, including for how much time you borrowed `&self` in the `get_inner` implementation. This means that enforce `'a` to be at most that statement or, to put it otherwise (as the Rust compiler), the actual lifetime or the borrow of your temporary should be at least `'a`, but that's not possible.